# How do you bundle assets from a node module with your gulp build?

Tags: npm, gulp, netlify

I am currently looking at deploying a personal project to Netlify. This project uses an npm package called NES.css which is found here: https://nostalgic-css.github.io/NES.css/.

I have a gulp file that has a build process that minifies, bundles, transpiles all the scss, js, images, etc. This is done by running `npm build`.

Netlify is setup to run this build command on deploy. Everything works as far as deploying goes, however, there are two images that the NES.css's stylesheet references that are no longer found because Netlify deletes the node modules before deploying your code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since nes.css just gives you a css to play with, you can easily fetch the css elements into your HTML via CDN by including the following in the `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/nes.css@latest/css/nes.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Bonus: With the above method, you don't need to worry about updating your nes.css npm module every time the original nes GitHub project gets an update.